# Cycles shader that renders its objects transparent when they are 'inside' of a sphere?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have a long line (thin cylinder) that runs through a semi-transparent sphere. Using the sphere as the cylinder's 'bounds', I would like the parts of the cylinder that are inside the sphere to render transparent. Is this possible with a cycles shader?

Answer (score 2):

I found that using the Transparent Depth output of the Light path node was the key for me.

I used a Math node to control its value which gave control over how much transparency was applied to the portion of the cylinder within the sphere.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using a Mix shader with a Transparent shader and e.g. a Diffuse or a Glossy shader as its input, and a Light Path node as its fac input. The Light Path node can be found under `Add` > `Input` in the node editor's menu.

Like this
[image]

Or this
[image]

The colour of the transparent shader needs to be pure white.